# python problems with usingpath variable

Tags: python-2.7, unix

There is a $CONFIG variable which stores the way to some dir on unix.
I created following python script to test path variable in unix.

```
import os

path=os.environ.get('$CONFIG')

if os.path.exists(path) is True:
    print '{} path exists'.format(path)
else:
    print 'problem'
```

It gives me an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    if os.path.exists(path) is True:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 18, in exists
    os.stat(path)
```

Woul you please help me how to correctly define path to unix folder using a variable in python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` from the variable and it may work. (`$` is used in linux terminal, not in python):

`path=os.environ.get('CONFIG')`